# VSCode formatting being overrided

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm developing in Angular and my vscode is on the fritz after almost a year of perfect formatting. More specifically when I click format doc. it indents with 2 spaces instead of 4. How can I fix this, or check what is overriding my settings?

My user and workspace settings (they are the same):

```
{
  "editor.fontSize": 16,
  "editor.tabSize": 4,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "editor.wordWrap": "off",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "editor.detectIndentation": true,
  "prettier.bracketSpacing": true,
  "prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
  "prettier.useTabs": false,
}
```

My extensions list:

[Angular Essentials](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.angular-essentials) (notice prettier is a dependency, and all other deps are installed)

[Bracket Pair Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer)
[language-vscode-javascript-angular2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nwallace.language-vscode-javascript-angular2)

edit:

also, it says indentation 2 spaces at the bottom of my editor, when i click it and click 4 spaces it says configured tab size. How come it is not setting this for every file if it is default?

Comment: I believe the `detectIndendation` setting will attempt to determine the current file's indentation settings and match those. This would affect existing files that have two space indent.

Comment: right, but these are on files I'm creating... unless each no file comes pre-indented?

Comment: I do not think that setting would affect new files. Is there an `.editorconfig` file? That can override settings on a "project" basis.

Comment: that's what I pasted above, my editorconfig. But I set the workspace and user settings the same

Comment: What is `"editor.tabSize"`? You don't show that.

Comment: sorry, it's 4, but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it could be the result of a two things:

### EditorConfig

Firstly, the `.editorconfig` file that was mentioned in the comments is a separate file (unrelated to VSCode specifically) that Angular generates. 
It serves as a guideline for any editor to read and obey, allowing developers to work on the same project with the same style, but multiple IDEs/editors of their choice.
It should look something like this:

```
# Editor configuration, see https://editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
max_line_length = off
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

As the comment already states, more info can be found at https://editorconfig.org.

In your case, you would want to change the `indent_size = 2` line to `indent_size = 4`.

### Angular CLI

If this doesn't do the trick, it could also be that Angular CLI is generating the files with 2 spaces and VSCode is detecting that indentation per your `"editor.detectIndentation": true` setting.
This was a hot topic [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1252) for awhile and was supppossed to be resolved by [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6272), but it didn't seem to help based on [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6272#issuecomment-315613588).

I fixed this using [Language Specific Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings) in VSCode.
I chose to force my tab size to 4 and disable indentation detection on all file types produced by the Angular.
You can drop this in your VSCode User Settings or follow [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings)) for the "correct" route.

```
{
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.detectIndentation": false
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.detectIndentation": false
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.detectIndentation": false
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.detectIndentation": false
    },
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.detectIndentation": false
    }
}
```

Adding `"editor.formatOnSave": true` or just hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Format Document) everywhere should do the trick.

`"editor.formatOnPaste": true` might also be useful if you paste 2-spaced example code often.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because the Angular Essentials Prettier plugin by default indents at 2, so you have to create a **separate** config for prettier in order for it to work.

see [this github post](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/344#issuecomment-360428558)